# Unsigned long long diffrent results

Tags: c

Why I got:

34458730320

3446590374

if I run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%llu\n",10248428203192896360LLU/594823321LLU*2LLU);
    printf("%llu\n",2LLU*10248428203192896360LLU/594823321LLU);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the second is correct (checked in Mathematica, Matlab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer value

```
2LLU * 10248428203192896360LLU
```

overflows 64 bits, and the compiler should warn about that.  The first is correct

```
10248428203192896360LLU / 594823321LLU * 2LLU
```

because the division is exact with no remainder, so it does not matter about doubling after the division was made.

Comment: 2LLU*10248428203192896360LLU>0LLU-1LLU YES a little :)